# How to embed and listen data over icmp in order to tunnel connection with using python

Tags: python, sockets, icmp, tunneling, libnet

i am trying to code one tunnel tool but i could not receive packet from icmp. I uses socket library, is there any one pylibnet or pynet library

Comment: How are you (attempting) capturing those packets? Code sample?

Comment: sock.recv(1024) is base of it

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/build_your_own_tools.html). On the other hand, have you seen the other [implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICMP_tunnel#External_links)?

Comment: scapy can not work on receive mode, there is a function called sr(send and receive)